# javascript replace() method takes function that takes 2 parameters?

Tags: javascript

I am reading Douglas Crockford's *Good Parts*, but I can't understand this code:

```
return this.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g, 
                    function(a, b) {
                        var r = entity[b];
                        return typeof r === 'string' ? r : a;
                        }
                    );
```

All I have seen is using `str.replace` with a function that takes one parameter. What happens when there are two parameters, where do the two parameters come from?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Permalink replace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: could you take a look on it, please - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15237211/4608582

Comment: @RobG please learn to read. I did not reference w3schools. My link is to MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a function as the second parameter, the parameters of the given function are cleary described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

> The nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument to
>   replace() was a RegExp object. (Corresponds to $1, $2, etc. above.)
>   For example, if /(\a+)(\b+)/, was given, p1 is the match for \a+, and
>   p2 for \b+.

Answer (score 0):

In `replace` you can [specify a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

The arguments of the function are:
`match, submatch1, submatch2, ..., offset, string`

where

- `match` is the whole match
- `submatch1, submatch2, ...` are the strings matching the respective parenthesized capturing groups
- `offset` is the position where the matching string starts in the whole string
- `string` is the whole string being examined

*Of course, the number of arguments of the functions will be dependent on the number of capturing groups in the regular expression*.

In your example there's one group hence the function can have up to 4 arguments.

```js
myString = "a&b;c a&&c;; ab;&;c";

myString = myString.replace(/&([^&;]+);/g, 
                    function(param0,param1,param2,param3) {
                        document.write("param0 = " + param0 + " (match)<br>");
                        document.write("param1 = " + param1 + " (first submatch)<br>");
                        document.write("param2 = " + param2 + " (offset)<br>");
                        document.write("param3 = " + param3 + " (whole string)<br>");    
                        document.write("<br>");
                        return "[" + param0 + "]";
                        }
                    );

document.write(myString);
```